# SED Command Replacement

Tags: linux, bash, sed, csh

Suppose I have a file with warnings. Each warning in a new line with an id that has **3 capital letters followed by 3 digits only**, should be replaced by its id.

Example:

```
SIM_WARNING[ANA397]: Node q<159> for vector output signal does not exist
```

The output should be ANA397 and the rest of line is deleted.

How to do so using sed?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: csh and bash are not the same thing, adjust tags accordingly.
Anyway, I tried to make a posix compliant answer (tested in bash 4.4-5, dash 0.5.8-2.4, posh 0.12.6+b1) so you should not have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need sed for that. A simple grep with `--only-matching` could do, as in:

```
grep -E 'SIM_WARNING\[(.)\]' --only-matching
```

should work for you.

Where:

- -E does "enhanced regular expressions. I *think* we need those for capturing with ( )
- then follows the pattern, which consists of the fixed SIM_WARNING, followed by a *match* inside the square brackets
- --only-matching simply makes grep print **only matching** content

In other words: by using ( match ) you tell grep that you only care about the thing in that match pattern.

Comment: could you please explain the syntax to me? what does --only matching mean?
to enumerate more, there are many lines in the file, some of them begin with the word "SIM_WARNING" and in each of these lines there is a square bracket with an ID of 3 capital letter and 3 digits. All I want is to replace these lines that starts  with "SIM_WARNING" with the ID it has in its line.

Comment: See my updates to the answer. But then understand that the IT business is about *knowing* what you are doing. You cant use sed, grep, ... without some basic knowledge of regular expressions, and how these work. Dont expect us to explain to you what is written up in many tutorials, or even in the grep --help help! And from there: start making experiments! Dont expect others to give you complete solutions. The essence of our business is to use "some inspiration" to then work stuff until you got it to work yourself!

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your help. I do appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. In case you found an answer helpful, consider accepting it at some point.

Comment: Of course. Could you please send me links for tutorials of both grep and sed? :)

Comment: Hint: google had birthday this month. Say hello to their search engine, and say "sed tutorial" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to choose how to use the IDs, for example if you need to cycle the file first or the IDs later...

E.G. (Cycle file first)

```
exec 3<file
while read -r line <&3; do
  id="$(printf "%s" "${line}" | sed -e "s/.*\[\([[:alnum:]]\+\)\].*/\1/")"
  ### Do something with id
done
exec 3>&-
```

Otherwise you can decide to cycle the output of sed...

E.G.

```
for id in $(sed -e "s/.*\[\([[:alnum:]]\+\)\].*/\1/" file); do
  ### Do something with id
done
```

Both of the examples should work with posix shell (If I am not missing something...), but shell like `posh` may not support classes as `[[:alnum:]]`, you can substitute them with the equivalent `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, as every [guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html) will teach you.

Note that the check is not on 3 letters and 3 digits, but for any letter and digit between brackets (`[` and `]`).

EDIT:
If your lines start with `SIM_WARNING` you can discriminates those lines with `-e "/^SIM_WARNING/! d"`

For a strict check on 3 letters and 3 digits you can use `-e "s/.*\[\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\].*/\1/"`

So taking the example above you can do somethin like:

```
for id in $(sed -e "/^SIM_WARNING/! d" -e "s/.*\[\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\].*/\1/" file)
  ### Do something with id
done
```

Comment: what if I want to check on the square brackets that they have 3 capital letters and 3 digits? Because there are some square brackets which doesn't have this identity. Also, each line that has the ID begins with "SIM_WARNING" sentence, can this make it easier?

Comment: I tried to edit the answer with this new piece of information [:

Answer (score 0):

```
for id in $(grep -o "^SIM_WARNING\[[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]\]" test1.bla | grep -o "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]" test1.bla ); do echo $id; done
```

This finds `ANA397` from the below.

```
SIM_WARNING[ANA397]: Node q<159> for vector output signal does not exist
```

Comment: It's required to use a simple sed command :(